# ngRepeat error when removing child directive from parent directive

Tags: angularjs

I´m having some issues with a gallery manager component where you can add/remove the pictures.

This is the html code of the gallery handler:

```
<img src = '{{snapshot}}' >
<div class = 'md-button l3' is-file ng-model = 'picture' blob-url = 'snapshot'>Upload</div>
<div class = 'md-button l3' ng-click = 'article.pictures.push(picture)'>Add</div>   

<div gallery-manager = 'article.pictures'></div>
```

Below, the directives:

```
.directive("galleryManager", function($compile){
        var controllerFn = function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            var self = this;        
            self.removeItemAt = function($index){
                self.pictures.splice($index, 1);
                $compile($element)($scope); <--Note this
            }
        }
        var linkFn = function($scope, $element, $attrs){
        }

        return {
            template:"<div gallery-item = 'picture' ng-repeat = 'picture in galleryManagerCtrl.pictures track by $index'></div>",
            restrict:"A",   
            controller:controllerFn,
            controllerAs:"galleryManagerCtrl",
            bindToController:{
                pictures:"=galleryManager",
            }
        }
    })
    .directive("galleryItem", function(FileService){
        var linkFn = function($scope, $element, $attrs, galleryManagerCtrl){
            $scope.galleryItemCtrl.galleryManagerCtrl = galleryManagerCtrl;
        }
        var controllerFn = function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            var self = this;
            if ( self.item instanceof File ){
                FileService.buildBlobUrl(self.item).then(function(blobUrl){
                    self.thumb = blobUrl;
                })
            }
        }
        return{
            template:"<img src = '{{galleryItemCtrl.thumb}}'>"+
                "<a class = 'delete' ng-click = 'galleryItemCtrl.galleryManagerCtrl.removeItemAt($index)'>&times</span></a>",
            restrict:"A",
            require:"^galleryManager",
            link:linkFn,
            controller:controllerFn,
            bindToController:{
                item:"=galleryItem",
            },
            controllerAs:"galleryItemCtrl"
        }
    })
```

Right now, the directive is working well when adding elements, but problems come when removing items; before using: $compile($element)($scope) after the deletion, in the gallery, always dissapeared the last item, although the pictures array removed the correct item, so I added the $compile line after deleting an item.

The problem is that, although the gallery now does what I want to, it keeps throwing an error after compiling (post the full trace, maybe it can help someone):

```
angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null
    at after (http://localhost/www/project/admin/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3644:13)
    at JQLite.(anonymous function) [as after] (http://localhost/www/project/admin/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3728:17)
    at domInsert (http://localhost/www/project/admin/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5282:35)
    at Object.move (http://localhost/www/project/admin/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5488:9)
    at ngRepeatAction (http://localhost/www/project/admin/bower_components/angular/angular.js:29865:26)
    at $watchCollectionAction (http://localhost/www/project/admin/bower_components/angular/angular.js:17385:13)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost/www/project/admin/bower_components/angular/angular.js:17524:23)
    at ChildScope.$apply (http://localhost/www/project/admin/bower_components/angular/angular.js:17790:24)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost/www/project/admin/bower_components/angular/angular.js:25890:23)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (http://localhost/www/project/admin/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3497:11)
```

That seems to come from watchCollection at ngRepeatDirective.

I have the feeling that I´m missing something basic, but can´t see what is right now, so, here I come to ask before digging into angular code.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Added a working sample:
http://codepen.io/sergio0983/pen/rMEMoJ?editors=1010

**EDIT 2**

Removed $compile from working sample, it makes it work, yes, but throws errors; and besides, I think the real problem is elsewhere. In the working sample, you can see how file names get updated when you delete an item, but the pictures keep their original order.

Comment: shouldn't have to use `$compile`. The `ng-repeat` watch will change view for you

Comment: If i don´t use the compile, always the last photo is removed (well, not really: the model is correct, but the view always remove lastPicture); i will try to make a code sample

Comment: indexing is probably not right, always best to do your own indexing in controller and not rely on `$index` ... especially if any filters are used

Comment: Have the same feeling, but didn´t found a faster way to get this. Anyway, I can remove the $index, but I don´t think that would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. add `addPicture()` function to your *mainController* (which will add constant unique ID ro the picture object):

   ```
   .controller("mainController", function($scope){
     $scope.article = {pictures:[]};
     $scope.addPicture = function addPicture (picture) {
       // set unique ID
       picture.id = $scope.article.pictures.length;
       $scope.article.pictures.push(picture);
     };
   })
   ```
2. change add button HTML to:

   ```
   <div class='md-button l3' ng-click='addPicture(picture)'>Add</div>
   ```
3. change *template* of *galleryManager* to `track by picture.id`:

   ```
   <div gallery-item='picture' 
        ng-repeat='picture in galleryManagerCtrl.pictures track by picture.id'></div>
   ```
4. modify `removeItemAt()` function, (`$compile` not needed here):

   ```
   self.removeItemAt = function removeItemAt (id) {
     // find index for the picture with given id
     id = self.pictures.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
     self.pictures.splice(id, 1);
   }
   ```

   modified codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mrZOre?editors=1010

Comment: Seems to work, I will mark as accepted answer as soon as I can deploy it (can´t test it right now). Want to check first if adding fields to a file object has some side effect, and, the id should be assigned inside the directive´s controller.