# How to Create an Image preview App using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, css

- User would be initially shown a screen with a card placeholder. There would be a plus button on the card.
- On clicking the plus button, the user would be prompted to select an image.
- Once the user selects an image, it would be shown in place of the card and a new placeholder card would be generated with a plus icon.
- Each image card would have a close button which on click should remove that particular image from the list. 
  please help me how to approach this above problem

Comment: Its good to copy & paste your requirements, and wait for somebody to create an app for you.Pay well mate! :)

Comment: hi Nikhil i did not expect you to create an app and give it to me. I just asked how to approach the above problem. just read the question before commenting mate

Answer (score 0):

here you can find very basic and simple implementation: [ngRepeat error when removing child directive from parent directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322978/ngrepeat-error-when-removing-child-directive-from-parent-directive/40324125#40324125). And here is my modifies `version`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mrZOre?editors=1010

Comment: Hi @Andriy, when i try to open the codepen its not opening. it is keep on refreshing. I am not able to see anything

Comment: sorry cant help with your browser, I can see it with Firefox and Chrome on windows... You should see 2 buttons 'Upload' and 'Add'